# .Net MVC Pass JSON To Controller Via AJAX

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here are my Models:

```
public class Inspection
{
    public string InspectionId { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class InspectionReasons : Inspection
{
    public string ReasonId { get; set; }
    public string ReasonDesc { get; set; }
    public string NotUsedInUpdate { get; set; }
    public bool CheckedFlag { get; set; }
}
```

I am getting this data from a dynamically built table and updating it via AJAX call:

```
table.rows().every(function (rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {
    var data = this.data();
    var row = this.node();
    var checked = $(row).find('input').prop('checked');

    reasons.push({
        InspectionId: data['id'],
        Description: data['desc'],
        ReasonId: data['reasonId'],
        ReasonDesc: data['reasonDesc'],
        CheckedFlag: checked,
        NotUsedInUpdate: ""
    });
});

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/InspectionReason/UpdateInpsectionReasons',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {
        reasons: JSON.stringify(reasons)
    }
});
```

And here is my action:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UpdateInpsectionReasons(List<InspectionReasons> reasons)
{
    UpdateReasons(reasons);
    return Json(string.Empty);
}
```

When I debug `List<InspectionReasons> reasons` is empty. I've alerted my client side reasons object and it is valid JSON. Do the properties need to be in the same order as they appear in the models? If they do, do the inherited properties go below the other properties? I see a lot of examples working like this but I can't seem to get mine to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax is missing ***contentType***. For example, `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Action("UpdateInpsectionReasons", "InspectionReason")',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(reasons),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

### Working Code

```
public class InspectionReasonController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateInpsectionReasons(List<InspectionReasons> reasons)
    {
        return Json(reasons);
    }
}
```

### View

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btnSubmit" type="button">Submit</button>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var reasons = [];

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            reasons.push({
                InspectionId: "Test InspectionId",
                Description: "Test Description",
                ReasonId: "Test ReasonId",
                ReasonDesc: "Test ReasonDesc",
                CheckedFlag: true,
                NotUsedInUpdate: "Test NotUsedInUpdate"
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("UpdateInpsectionReasons", "InspectionReason")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: JSON.stringify(reasons),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That got me further! I am now getting an error "Invalid JSON Primative: reasons". I changed my controller from a JsonResult to an ActionResult type. Would that have anything to do with the new error? It's failing before it returns anything so I can't see how it would be.

Comment: At the AJAX call. It doesn't even drop into my public ActionResult. I am working on getting my actual JSON object to show what I'm passing in.

Comment: [{"DisasterNum":"9001","RegId":"150304791","InspectionSeq":"2","ReviewReasonId":"159","Checked":true,"ReviewDesc":"","PriorityId":"","PriorityDesc":"","Sort":""}]  

This is my actual json. I know it doesn't match my generic example, but it looks valid to me.

I'll work with what you've given and see what I come up with.

Comment: I'll be damned. It seems like valid JSON, but when I copy to Visual Studio, VS complains that one of `:` is a special character. Here is the [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sq6MR.png)

Comment: I was able to get your example to work. I will work backwards from there and fine where my disconnect is. Thanks!!!